# vmware player 12.5.5 "Unable to start services"

Tags: vmware

I installed VMware player 12.5.5 64bit and I get the following error when trying to run it

> Unable to start services.
>   See log file /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-7699.log for details.

Can someone please help?  I've been searching but to no luck.

```
2017-04-26T14:49:41.308+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Log for VMware Workstation 
pid=7699 version=12.5.1 build=build-4542065 option=Release
2017-04-26T14:49:41.308+12:00| vthread-4| I125: The process is 64-bit.
2017-04-26T14:49:41.308+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Host codepage=UTF-8 encoding=UTF-8
2017-04-26T14:49:41.308+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Host is Linux 4.10.0-19-generic Ubuntu 17.04
2017-04-26T14:49:41.307+12:00| vthread-4| I125: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/settings": No such file or directory.
2017-04-26T14:49:41.307+12:00| vthread-4| I125: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /usr/lib/vmware/settings. Using default values.
2017-04-26T14:49:41.307+12:00| vthread-4| I125: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/root/.vmware/config": No such file or directory.
2017-04-26T14:49:41.307+12:00| vthread-4| I125: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /root/.vmware/config. Using default values.
2017-04-26T14:49:41.307+12:00| vthread-4| I125: PREF Unable to check permissions for preferences file.
2017-04-26T14:49:41.307+12:00| vthread-4| I125: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/root/.vmware/preferences": No such file or directory.
2017-04-26T14:49:41.307+12:00| vthread-4| I125: PREF Failed to load user preferences.
2017-04-26T14:49:41.341+12:00| vthread-4| W115: Logging to /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-7699.log
2017-04-26T14:49:41.347+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2017-04-26T14:49:41.347+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Created new pathsHash.
2017-04-26T14:49:41.347+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting header path for 4.10.0-19-generic to "/lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/include".
2017-04-26T14:49:41.347+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.10.0-19-generic".
2017-04-26T14:49:41.347+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2017-04-26T14:49:41.347+12:00| vthread-4| I125: /lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2017-04-26T14:49:41.347+12:00| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2017-04-26T14:49:41.350+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.10.0-19-generic".
2017-04-26T14:49:41.350+12:00| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.10.0-19-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2017-04-26T14:49:41.446+12:00| vthread-4| I125: found symbol version file /lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/Module.symvers
2017-04-26T14:49:41.446+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2017-04-26T14:49:41.461+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Read 21363 symbol versions
2017-04-26T14:49:41.462+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading in info for the vmmon module.
2017-04-26T14:49:41.462+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading in info for the vmnet module.
2017-04-26T14:49:41.462+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading in info for the vmblock module.
2017-04-26T14:49:41.462+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading in info for the vmci module.
2017-04-26T14:49:41.462+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading in info for the vsock module.
2017-04-26T14:49:41.462+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting vsock to depend on vmci.
2017-04-26T14:49:41.462+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmmon".
2017-04-26T14:49:41.463+12:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2017-04-26T14:49:41.463+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmnet".
2017-04-26T14:49:41.464+12:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2017-04-26T14:49:41.464+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmblock".
2017-04-26T14:49:41.464+12:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2017-04-26T14:49:41.464+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmci".
2017-04-26T14:49:41.465+12:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2017-04-26T14:49:41.465+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vsock".
2017-04-26T14:49:41.466+12:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 0.
2017-04-26T14:49:41.476+12:00| vthread-4| I125: to be installed: vmmon status: 0
2017-04-26T14:49:41.476+12:00| vthread-4| I125: to be installed: vmnet status: 0
2017-04-26T14:49:41.488+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2017-04-26T14:49:41.488+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting header path for 4.10.0-19-generic to "/lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/include".
2017-04-26T14:49:41.488+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.10.0-19-generic".
2017-04-26T14:49:41.488+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2017-04-26T14:49:41.488+12:00| vthread-4| I125: /lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2017-04-26T14:49:41.488+12:00| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2017-04-26T14:49:41.492+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.10.0-19-generic".
2017-04-26T14:49:41.492+12:00| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.10.0-19-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2017-04-26T14:49:41.581+12:00| vthread-4| I125: found symbol version file /lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/Module.symvers
2017-04-26T14:49:41.581+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2017-04-26T14:49:41.595+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Read 21363 symbol versions
2017-04-26T14:49:41.595+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Kernel header path retrieved from FileEntry: /lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/include
2017-04-26T14:49:41.595+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Update kernel header path to /lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/include
2017-04-26T14:49:41.595+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.10.0-19-generic".
2017-04-26T14:49:41.595+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2017-04-26T14:49:41.595+12:00| vthread-4| I125: /lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2017-04-26T14:49:41.595+12:00| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2017-04-26T14:49:41.599+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.10.0-19-generic".
2017-04-26T14:49:41.599+12:00| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.10.0-19-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2017-04-26T14:49:41.599+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Found compiler at "/usr/bin/gcc"
2017-04-26T14:49:41.601+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Got gcc version "6.3.0".
2017-04-26T14:49:41.601+12:00| vthread-4| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2017-04-26T14:49:41.601+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Using user supplied compiler "/usr/bin/gcc".
2017-04-26T14:49:41.603+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Got gcc version "6.3.0".
2017-04-26T14:49:41.603+12:00| vthread-4| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2017-04-26T14:49:41.603+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel "4.10.0-19-generic".
2017-04-26T14:49:41.603+12:00| vthread-4| I125: No matching PBM set was found for kernel "4.10.0-19-generic".
2017-04-26T14:49:41.603+12:00| vthread-4| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2017-04-26T14:49:41.603+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.10.0-19-generic".
2017-04-26T14:49:41.603+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2017-04-26T14:49:41.603+12:00| vthread-4| I125: /lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2017-04-26T14:49:41.603+12:00| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2017-04-26T14:49:41.607+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.10.0-19-generic".
2017-04-26T14:49:41.607+12:00| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.10.0-19-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2017-04-26T14:49:41.608+12:00| vthread-4| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2017-04-26T14:49:41.608+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.10.0-19-generic".
2017-04-26T14:49:41.608+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2017-04-26T14:49:41.608+12:00| vthread-4| I125: /lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2017-04-26T14:49:41.608+12:00| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2017-04-26T14:49:41.611+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.10.0-19-generic".
2017-04-26T14:49:41.611+12:00| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.10.0-19-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2017-04-26T14:49:41.611+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Using temp dir "/tmp".
2017-04-26T14:49:41.612+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2017-04-26T14:49:41.612+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting header path for 4.10.0-19-generic to "/lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/include".
2017-04-26T14:49:41.612+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.10.0-19-generic".
2017-04-26T14:49:41.612+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2017-04-26T14:49:41.612+12:00| vthread-4| I125: /lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2017-04-26T14:49:41.612+12:00| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2017-04-26T14:49:41.616+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.10.0-19-generic".
2017-04-26T14:49:41.616+12:00| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.10.0-19-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2017-04-26T14:49:41.704+12:00| vthread-4| I125: found symbol version file /lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/Module.symvers
2017-04-26T14:49:41.704+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2017-04-26T14:49:41.719+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Read 21363 symbol versions
2017-04-26T14:49:41.719+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmmon".
2017-04-26T14:49:41.720+12:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2017-04-26T14:49:41.720+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmnet".
2017-04-26T14:49:41.721+12:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2017-04-26T14:49:42.050+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting destination path for vmmon to "/lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/misc/vmmon.ko".
2017-04-26T14:49:42.050+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Extracting the vmmon source from "/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmmon.tar".
2017-04-26T14:49:42.056+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Successfully extracted the vmmon source.
2017-04-26T14:49:42.056+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j4 -C /tmp/modconfig-mlfOs2/vmmon-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc IS_GCC_3=no"
2017-04-26T14:49:43.409+12:00| vthread-4| W115: Failed to build vmmon.  Failed to execute the build command.
2017-04-26T14:49:43.410+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting destination path for vmnet to "/lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/misc/vmnet.ko".
2017-04-26T14:49:43.410+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Extracting the vmnet source from "/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmnet.tar".
2017-04-26T14:49:43.414+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Successfully extracted the vmnet source.
2017-04-26T14:49:43.415+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j4 -C /tmp/modconfig-mlfOs2/vmnet-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc IS_GCC_3=no"
2017-04-26T14:49:44.439+12:00| vthread-4| W115: Failed to build vmnet.  Failed to execute the build command.
2017-04-26T15:06:59.410+12:00| vthread-4| I125: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2017-04-26T15:06:59.410+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.10.0-19-generic".
2017-04-26T15:06:59.410+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2017-04-26T15:06:59.410+12:00| vthread-4| I125: /lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2017-04-26T15:06:59.410+12:00| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2017-04-26T15:06:59.421+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.10.0-19-generic".
2017-04-26T15:06:59.421+12:00| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.10.0-19-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2017-04-26T15:06:59.421+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Using temp dir "/tmp".
2017-04-26T15:06:59.422+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2017-04-26T15:06:59.422+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting header path for 4.10.0-19-generic to "/lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/include".
2017-04-26T15:06:59.422+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Validating path "/lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/include" for kernel release "4.10.0-19-generic".
2017-04-26T15:06:59.422+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2017-04-26T15:06:59.422+12:00| vthread-4| I125: /lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2017-04-26T15:06:59.422+12:00| vthread-4| I125: using /usr/bin/gcc for preprocess check
2017-04-26T15:06:59.427+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "4.10.0-19-generic".
2017-04-26T15:06:59.427+12:00| vthread-4| I125: The header path "/lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/include" for the kernel "4.10.0-19-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2017-04-26T15:06:59.533+12:00| vthread-4| I125: found symbol version file /lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/Module.symvers
2017-04-26T15:06:59.533+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2017-04-26T15:06:59.549+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Read 21363 symbol versions
2017-04-26T15:06:59.549+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmmon".
2017-04-26T15:06:59.551+12:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2017-04-26T15:06:59.551+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Invoking modinfo on "vmnet".
2017-04-26T15:06:59.553+12:00| vthread-4| I125: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2017-04-26T15:07:00.013+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting destination path for vmmon to "/lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/misc/vmmon.ko".
2017-04-26T15:07:00.013+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Extracting the vmmon source from "/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmmon.tar".
2017-04-26T15:07:00.019+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Successfully extracted the vmmon source.
2017-04-26T15:07:00.019+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j4 -C /tmp/modconfig-TLkrfy/vmmon-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc IS_GCC_3=no"
2017-04-26T15:07:01.350+12:00| vthread-4| W115: Failed to build vmmon.  Failed to execute the build command.
2017-04-26T15:07:01.351+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Setting destination path for vmnet to "/lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/misc/vmnet.ko".
2017-04-26T15:07:01.351+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Extracting the vmnet source from "/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmnet.tar".
2017-04-26T15:07:01.356+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Successfully extracted the vmnet source.
2017-04-26T15:07:01.356+12:00| vthread-4| I125: Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j4 -C /tmp/modconfig-TLkrfy/vmnet-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc IS_GCC_3=no"
2017-04-26T15:07:02.285+12:00| vthread-4| W115: Failed to build vmnet.  Failed to execute the build command.
```

Comment: Did you have your kernel headers installed? If not install `sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`